# Alternative to & and %26

Tags: html

I am having an issue where sending an sms through a hyperlink the url sent gets cut off after the first "&"

I have tried replacing the & in the code with %26 however it has the same effect

```html
<a href="sms:?body=Open%20Doors%20Challenge https%3A%2F%2Fjoseph.technologyforthefuture.org%2Fopen-doors-challenge%2F%3FmA%3Dtrue%26y=8">Test SMS</a>
```

I had expected that putting %26 would have at least worked for the url but It did not it gets cut off right after "mA=true"

Comment: Sounds like a bug in whatever software is handling the URL.

Comment: Tested on 2 iphones and android with same result @Quentin

Answer (score -3):

Try `%2526` instead of `&` or `%26` as `%25` should mean the `%` sign, in the `%26` construct...
EG:

```
<a href="sms:?body=Open%20Doors%20Challenge https%3A%2F%2Fjoseph.technologyforthefuture.org%2Fopen-doors-challenge%2F%3FmA%3Dtrue%2526y=8">Test SMS</a>
```

Comment: Doing this the body of the sms becomes blank\